# Remove Element From Map Using Filter

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a java.util.Map inside an rx.Observable and I want to filter the map (remove an element based on a given key).

My current code is a mix of imperative and functional, I want to accomplish this goal without the call to `isItemInDataThenRemove`.

```
public static Observable<Map<String, Object>> filter(Map<String, Object> data, String removeKey) {
    return Observable.from(data).filter((entry) -> isItemInDataThenRemove(entry,removeKey));
}

private static boolean isItemInDataThenRemove(Map<String, Object> data, String removeKey) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(removeKey)) {
            System.out.printf("Found element %s, removing.", removeKey);
            data.remove(removeKey);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The code does work. I want to do it in a more functional way instead of doing the for - each loop.

Comment: If your code works and you want to have *different* code that has the same result, please post *that*. SO is not a site for questions like "I want this result, please write code for me." Show us what you have tried to reach your goal.

Comment: Another option I am working on:

    data.entrySet().stream().filter(entry->entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(removeKey)).forEach(entry-> {data.remove(entry.getKey());});

Comment: Have you thought about using a Bidi Map? You'd have to convert the keys all to a single case (based on your use of equalsIgnoreCase), but it's way more efficient than continually looping over the entire map.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have proposed has a general problem in that it modifies the underlying stream while operating on it.  This conflicts with the general requirement for streams for [non-interference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), and often in practice means that you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when using streams pipelines with containers that remove objects in the underlying container.

In any case (as I learned yesterday) there is a new default method on the `Collection` class that does pretty much exactly what you want:

```
private static boolean isItemInDataThenRemove(Map<String, Object> data, String removeKey) {
    return data.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(removeKey));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WORKING CODE:

```
private static boolean isItemInDataThenRemove(Map<String, Object> data, String removeKey) {
    data.entrySet().stream().filter(entry ->
            entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(removeKey)).forEach(entry -> {
        data.remove(entry.getKey());
    });
    return true;
}
```